# Folding of curves in Tristan Needham's proof of Hopf Umlaufsatz

Tags: differential-geometry

> [image]
> Pg -178,
> Let us illustrate and clarify these ideas with a concrete example. If C is a circle, then as x orbits
> C once, its image $\tilde{x} = N(x)$ orbits $S^1$ once, with matching angular speed. Clearly, deg[N(C)] = +1.
> Now suppose that we gradually and symmetrically deform the circle, so that C takes the form
> shown on the left of [17.4], resembling the cross section of a pear.
>
> For the illustrated point $\tilde{q}$ on S
> 1
> there is precisely one preimage q on C. But for point $\tilde{p}$ there
> are instead three preimages p1, p2, p3.
>
> A helpful mental device in locating these preimages of $\tilde{p}$ is to first observe that the tangent
> to S
> 1 at $\tilde{p}$(not shown) must be parallel to the tangent to C at each preimage of $\tilde{p}$. Now imagine
> taking this tangent line at $\tilde{p}$ and letting it move parallel to itself towards C, ultimately sweeping
> across all of C. Note each time the moving line touches C: these include all the preimages of $\tilde{p}$, but
> they also include the preimages of the antipodal point −$\tilde{p}$
>
> Restricting attention to the right hand side of C, we observe that there are precisely two inflection points, a and b, distinguished by the fact that C crosses the tangent line at these points, and
> only at these points.
> To see that the inflection points play a crucial role in relation to the spherical/normal map N,
> imagine x starting at q and travelling up the right side of C. Then $\tilde{x}$ = N(x) travels forward along
> S
> 1
> from $\tilde{q}$ through be and $\tilde{p}$ until it hits $\tilde{a}$. But at $\tilde{a}$ it bounces and travels backwards, passing through
> $\tilde{p}$ for a second time before hitting be. Now it bounces again and resumes its forward motion along
> S
> 1
> , passing through $\tilde{p}$ a third time. Next it arrives at $\tilde{a}$ for a second time
>
> Pg-179, Now comes a crucial mental leap in the visualization of this motion: think of the motion of $\tilde{x}$ as the orbit of a bead travelling along a continuous, unbroken thread. Thus, as illustrated, when $\tilde{x}$ first arrives at $\tilde{a}$ and starts to move backwards on $\mathbb{S}^1$ , it can only be because the thread has folded back on itself a second time. Thus, as illustrated, as x passes through $p_1$, then $p_2$ , and finally $p_3$, $\tilde{x}$ passes through $\tilde{p}$ three times, first forward, then backward along the folded thread, then forward again along the twice-folded thread.
> contin

I am having difficulty understanding what exactly is the meaning of "curve being folded back on itself" and "twice folded". From google, this is the definition of folding

> bend (something flexible and relatively flat) over on itself so that one part of it covers another. [source](https://www.google.com/search?q=fold%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvJ2Mufy-q7LHEGGViAcxZZ90L5qaQ%3A1641114125159&ei=DWrRYZ-GCaabseMP7Mq8-AM&ved=0ahUKEwjfwNzD2pL1AhWmTWwGHWwlDz8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=fold%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEJECMggIABCABBCxAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgQIABBDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToHCAAQsQMQQzoKCAAQgAQQsQMQCjoLCAAQgAQQsQMQyQNKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQnAdY9Q5gqg9oAXACeACAAZ4BiAH5CpIBBDAuMTGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

It seems to me that the above definition is non sensical here because we are not covering anything with anything other. Maybe it could be that a different definition of folding is being used.

Could someone please explain what Tristan Needham is trying to convey in simpler words? Thanks.

Comment: What is the title of the book of T. Needham ? Is it Visual Complex Analysis ?

Comment: No, it's actually the new one. Visual Differential Geometry @Jean Marie

Comment: Look at different representations like those you will find [here](https://readingfeynman.org/tag/riemann-surface/) beginning by the first image (double cover by the Riemann surface associated with $\sqrt{z}$ for which "you need 2 turns in order to be again on the right tracks..").

Comment: I'll check it out when I get some free time

Comment: I'm confused how does that multi valued function thingy relate to the stuff going on here @JeanMarie

Comment: If you follow the frontier curve of this Riemann surface, you make two turns before coming back to the original point, but if you consider the projected curve, you see a circle on which you have made two turns. The first one is the 'lifted version' of the second one.

Comment: I checked the blog, and I really liked it but frankly I feel I still didn't understand. Could you give like a dumbed down explanation with more pictures that could help me understand? @JeanMarie

Comment: see the little answer I just made. Is this drawing more helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

An illustration (using Geogebra) of a "curve being folded back on itself" or "twice folded" giving a "double cover".

Have a look at the following space curve, with equations:

$$x=\sin(t), \ \ y=\cos(t), \ \ z=\sin(t/2)$$

with a double point in $(1,0,0)$.

It is drawn on a cylinder with radius $1$.

Its period is $4 \pi$ ; it covers (in the sense of "spreading a vertical shadow") twice its projection, the unit circle, before coming back in the same position with the same tangent vector. This is a way to materialize the fact that a $2 \pi$ angle is not automatically the same as a $0$ angle...

[image]

Comment: I think some more cases would help in understanding. I am not exactly sure what part of the ccurve should be put in attention

Answer (score 0):

I think I sort of understood it now. Here is an attempt at an explanation, suppose we parameterize the deformed circle by a parameter $t$ i.e: $\gamma:\left[0,1 \right] \to \gamma(t)$.

Let $\theta(t)$ be the function which measures the rotation of normal from a reference normal on the curve (you can choose any normal of a point on curve for this). To have folding simply means to have some collection points  with $\theta'(t)=0$.

Geometrically this translates to push out / pushing inside the circle as shown in the diagram.